# calling a parent constructor C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Is there any advantage to calling the parent constructor explicitly in the derived class constructor?

is this:

```
LockableDoor :: LockableDoor() : Door(), locked_(true) { }
```

is different from this:

```
LockableDoor :: LockableDoor() : locked_(true) { }
```

somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just provides the way you select appropriate parent constructor and pass parameters to it. No other advantages.
In your example there is no difference between 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a *default constructor* you want then you can leave it as compiler would automatically call it for you. But it's good for readability to explicitly call that *constructor*.

Comment: I disagree on the second statement. I prefer not to have it, it clutters the code for nothing since as you mentioned the compiler will call it for us.

Answer (score 1):

It's not different, but the answer to your question is yes, it is sometimes advantageous to call parent constructors. That's the case when you want to call something other than the constructor with no arguments (especially if you have none of those):

```
A::A(int) {}
B::B(int i): A(i) {}       // derived from A
```

Comment: In some cases it's not just advantageous but necessary (if for example the default ctor is unavailable)